# Android ListView setOnScrollListener

Tags: android, listview

I'm having problem with my setOnScrollListener. It just keeps calling my asynctask whenever I scroll to the bottom of the listview. How do I set the setOnScrollListener to load only once I reach the bottom.

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
mProgressDialog.dismiss();

listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if (lastInScreen == totalItemCount) {
            new loadmore().execute();
        } else {
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OnScroll method is called whenever you scroll down the list view, so the best bet for you to is to use some kind of padding, like the one implemented [here](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/).

```
public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener 

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }
    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
            // but you can call any function here.
            new LoadGigsTask().execute(currentPage + 1);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
}
```

**visibleThreshold** – The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position, before loading more.

**currentPage** – The current page of data you have loaded

**previousTotal** – The total number of items in the dataset after the last load

**loading** – True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.

Comment: Anytime bro, just helping a brother out :-P.

Comment: @mushtaq can you please tell me what should we code in `class LoadGigsTask()` i mean the logic behind it. and how to use the `currentPage` in webservice(like json) to retrieve more posts and update listview.

Comment: @Ankxx13 - Sorry I could not reply immediately. But that is basically an asynchronous call in android. This is basically done to do any push any heavy lifting acting to a background thread so that the main screen does not freeze.Here you can do a Web Service call to and get a JSON response and parse it and add it to the list view,  the currentPage acts like a marker telling you @ which record you should fetch from, you all this logic would go into your back-end that does the data processing.

Comment: @Ankxx13 - Here are some links that might be useful http://java.avdiel.com/Tutorials/JDBCPaging.html http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/

Comment: @mushtaq Thank you for your response. Now i understood what i should code(Query) in the back-end file. The attribute LIMIT is all i should balance of queering

Comment: it calls the paging method multiple times on fling

Comment: @mushtaq can you help ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122304/endless-scrolling-listview-not-working