# How to display unlimited list of data in Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, lazy-loading

I really apologize if this question has already been answered. 
I have not found any appropriate solution for the issue i am facing.

I have large an amount of data.

Which is  i want to display in List ,this data contains *images,urls,title,type and price*.

List of the items can be more than `10,000`.

So if i am to implement `Lazy Loading` i need all the urls and rest of the data so that i can load the images at run time .

But how do i load the data which contains the urls, titles, type and price list?.

Or can i load first the 20 records by lazy loading. If yes then how?

**Please suggest if you have an better approach to getting this thing done.**

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: yes, use pagination concept for loading data.https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/PagingListView

Comment: Look at my ans how to load image from url which provide you best way to load image in List in async manner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086192/setting-imageview-in-android/19086298#19086298

Comment: @SandeepTiwari can you please explain this?

Comment: @SandeepTiwari  i am able to import this project some xmls are missing

Comment: you can also see this, Hope it will help you.  http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

Answer (score 1):

you can load 20 records at first and further more records when scrolling the ListView, by using `ScrollListener` for your `ListView`. [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473933/android-listview-setonscrolllistener#answer-17474237)

Answer (score 1):

How i do this is that i load data (suppose 20 item) in ArrayList using AsyncTask then i set them to listview by using setAdapter and in getView method of ListAdapter as it reach to second last item i
execute the AsyncTask again but this time instead of setAdapter i use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
how it should be is :
**getView method should be like this :**

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
{
    //your data inflater or set text...
    if(arg0==yourList.size()-1)
       {
           new YourAsyncTask().execute());
       }
}
```

**AsyncTask Should Be Like this**

```
//first initialize your list out of asynctask 
ArrayList<String> yourList=new ArrayList<String>();

class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask(Void,Void,Void)
 {
     protected Void doInBackground(String ... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //get your data and add to arraylist
             yourlist.add(data);
      }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
             if(yourlist.size<20){
                   listview.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
                }
              else
                 {
                    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its entirely depends on how you architect the app.One approach I would preffer is to make one request to server which will return you urls,titles data in json format.

```
{
    "dummy_info": "blah blah blah",
    "data": [
        {
            "url": "http://www.google.com",
            "title": "Sample",
            "type": "Education",
            "price": "50$"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://www.google.com",
            "title": "Sample",
            "type": "Education",
            "price": "50$"
        }
    ]
}
```

Once you get that particular data then you can use Android [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) OR Lazy List loading implementation to fetch data in batches.

Comment: thats what i am implementing. FIrst i want to get the data then load the image but the time scroll. But the if the data/list is too long then how it will work?