# How to add load more button in android listview for offline content?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `listview` and an array of say 30 items in it, now I want to show first 10 items only when I open it, and then as I scroll to bottom I want to show a load more button which when clicked will add next 10 items  to the `listview` and again on scrolling to bottom it should show load more button. I just don't know how to handle this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473933/android-listview-setonscrolllistener and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000964/how-to-implement-setonscrolllistener-in-recyclerview may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
listv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                if(flag_loading == false)
                {
                    flag_loading = true;
                    addmoreitems();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and then you can add next ten items in addmoreitems(). it will work.

If you want to add button at footer of listview just add yourlistview.addFooterView. Just try this [code](http://pastie.org/10913817)

Answer (score 0):

We can add **Load More** button to list view using `listview.addFooterView(btnLoadMore)` then, we can ada a click event listener to load more button and call a background thread which will append more data to listview.

here is the complete tutorial on [listview with load more button](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/)

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes to ListAdapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
....
if (mTotalPages > mData.size()) {

    if ((position + 1) == getCount()) {
        holder.sLoadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.sLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

  ....
}
```

Where **mTotalPages = 30** in your case.

In adapter layout add load more view at the bottom like this,

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/loading_more_items"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content_wrapper"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/space"

    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"

    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```